# KeyError at /socket.io

Tags: python, django, django-socketio

I am using django-socketio in one of my project and also installed all dependencies belongs to this app. But after the execution, it shows an error like below:

> KeyError at /socket.io

```
socket = SocketIOChannelProxy(request.environ["socketio"])
```

I'm using django 1.8,django-socketio 0.3.9, gevent 0.13.6, gevent-socketio 0.2.1 and gevent-websocket 0.9.5 for this project. I don't know whether it is a dependency issue as some sites mentioned like the same. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You might want to see where the exception is being raised, and analyze whats going on. Are you familiar with pdb ?

Comment: @karthikr Actually the error is raised inside the views of django-socketio. A key named ''socketio' is missing inside the request.